# How do I update my ImageFolder dataset in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am working on a dataset where I am required to find accuracy of classes with less than 20 samples. So first I used pytorch's ImageFolder to get all the images in the folders.

```
dataset = ImageFolder('/content/drive/MyDrive/data/Dataset/')
```

Now to get classes with less than 20 samples I use:

```
def get_class_distribution(dataset_obj):
    count_dict = {k:0 for k,v in dataset_obj.class_to_idx.items()}
    
    for element in dataset_obj:
        y_lbl = element[1]
        y_lbl = idx2class[y_lbl]
        count_dict[y_lbl] += 1
            
    return count_dict
# print("Distribution of classes: \n", get_class_distribution(dataset))
class_distribution = get_class_distribution(dataset)

sampled_classes = [classes  for (classes, samples) in class_distribution.items() if samples <= 20]
```

I get the list of classes correctly but my doubt is how do I proceed further for inference? How do I convert/update it to ImageFolder so that I can use the filtered dataset in the following code:

```
# Test model performance for classes with less than 20 samples.

y_pred_list = []
y_true_list = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for x_batch, y_batch in tqdm(data_loader):
        x_batch, y_batch = x_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
        y_test_pred = model(x_batch)
        _, y_pred_tag = torch.max(y_test_pred, dim = 1)
        y_pred_list.append(y_pred_tag.cpu().numpy())
        y_true_list.append(y_batch.cpu().numpy())
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of writing 1st block
use this instead

```
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder('test/', transform=test_transforms)
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=16)

y_pred_list = []
accuracy = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for x_batch, y_batch in tqdm(data_loader):
        x_batch, y_batch = x_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
        y_test_pred = model(x_batch)
        top_p, top_class = y_test_pred.topk(1, dim=1)
        equals = top_class == y_batch.view(*top_class.shape)
        accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()


print(accuracy/len(data_loader)*100) # this would print %
```

Comment: Can you please explain? How does this apply for classes with less than 20 samples?

Comment: this is independent of no. of samples..provided your `data_loader` is `ImageFolder` instance

Comment: there was no need for writng the 1st block that you have written

Comment: But I want the accuracy on the classes with less than 20 samples only. Not the entire dataset.

Comment: yes bro,,,,place only 20 images in that data_folder...its the same(single folder for each class)

Comment: Okay so let me get this straight. I have a dataset with 258 folders (classes) . So you are saying find the folders (classes) with images (samples) that are less than 20 and then place them in separate folder which in your case is 'test/' and then perform your solution?

Comment: hmm. seems a bit inefficient/tedious. But I'll try.

Comment: Can you tell me what is labels? Is it a tensor? where did you get that from?

Comment: it's labels...my mistake...i hav changed the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234220/discussion-between-harry-r-and-prajot-kuvalekar).